# JavaScript graphing library which supports line graphs with missing data

Tags: javascript, graph

I am looking for a charting library that supports creating graphs with missing data.
A bit of an odd request, but required for my application as my DB doesn't always have a complete data set.

I'm currently using [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create a line graph, however because there are holes in my data, it is causing my graph to look quite messy.

The graph contains months on the x axis, and a users score on the y axis. There is one year of data, broken in months... and then the user score ranges from 0 - 10

However, sometimes I end up with months with no data, and it is causing NaN for that month. Does anyone know of a graph library that supports missing data, or a work around solution for such an issue?

Comment: not sure about this specific case, but you might want to check out jqwidgets, they have quite a few charts and i find their documentation to be very helpful, plenty of custom callbacks, data sources...etc....     http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm

Comment: Look into Google Visualization API, https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually refer to [chart.js](http://chartjs.org)

[ChartJS](http://chartjs.devexpress.com) supports [missing data](http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Demos/VizGallery/#chart/chartsadvancedfeaturesnullpointsupport)